# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices, when trying to drop columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop some columns but I wanted to set a variable which numbers the columns I would like to drop instead of hard-coding it.

My Code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(WorkdayExcelPathName,low_memory=(False))

ColumnsToDrop = df.iloc[:, [57,125]]

df2 = df.drop(df.columns[ColumnsToDrop], axis = 1)

print(df2)
```

which gives me this error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I have also tried using:

```
ColumnsToDrop = df.iloc[:, np.r_[57,125]]
```

But it continues to produce the same **IndexError** error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure you can list indices like that with `iloc`. I think it expects slicing parameters and not a list of indices. An example in the doc proposes `df.iloc[:, lambda df: [57, 125]]`. However an alternative should be possible using `df.drop(df.columns[[57, 125]], axis = 1, inplace = True)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
df.drop(df.columns[[57, 125]], axis=1)
```

or this if you want it to look more like what you already have

```
ColumnsToDrop = df.iloc[:, [57, 125]].columns

df2 = df.drop(ColumnsToDrop, axis=1)
```